# SQL query to get top performer statistics per year (eg 3 pointers)

Tags: sql, max, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with players per year and some stats.
For example (player_key, player_name, year, 3point_trials, 3point_score)

I want to have as an ouput the top performer per year (3point_score/3point_trials). If two of them have the same % then the breakeven is the the 3point_trials, whoever has the most trials.

Output would be per year

```
Name, Year, %score, trials
Player1 2000 55 1200
Player2 2001 61 1001
Player1 2002 54 978
Player6 2003 63 1034
Player5 2004 59 1132
.....
```

what is the SQL query for this output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend window functions:

```
select p.*
from (
    select p.*, 100.0 * 3point_score / 3point_trials score_percent,
        rank() over(partition by year order by 100.0 * 3point_score / 3point_trials desc, 3point_trials desc) rn
    from players p
) p
where rn = 1
order by year, rn
```

Comment: @Serg: right! This **3**-pointers thing had me bugging.

Comment: It works! Is there any simpler way by just using simple functions, like group by, order by and limit?